# Maven get LATEST Snapshot or Release

Tags: maven, version, maven-3, maven-plugin, release

I want to use profiles which resolves the latest versions of my project.
The current project with the profiles does not change... only the version needs to be updated and I dont want to touch every few weeks the project to adjust the version of my Plugins.

```
    <profile>
        <id>productive</id>
        <properties>
            <myPluginsVersion>RELEASE</myPluginsVersion>
        </properties>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>development</id>
        <properties>
            <myPluginsVersion>LATEST</myPluginsVersion>
        </properties>
    </profile>
```

The use of LATEST or RELEASE are depreacted with maven 3.x. Is there another way? I used already the versions-plugin with update properties. But this plugin updated all my properties an the project was noct working any more. I only want to update myPluginsVersion automatically without touching the project with the profiles.

Comment: Have you tried `versions:update-property`? It allows you to set a specific property and a range of versions, where you can use something like `[1.5,)` for "version 1.5 or higher".

Comment: I tried range of versions. But if I want the Release-version it downloads the Snapshot version. Is versions:update-property get the Latest Release or Snapshot version or do I have to the set the version which I want?

Comment: https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/update-property-mojo.html#newVersion says that the standard behaviour is to _not_ load snapshots, but there is a parameter allowSnapshots for it

Comment: I tried the plugin and it works good... but it updates the pom.xml which needs to be saved.... which means, I have to update the pom.xml everytime.

Comment: Maven follows the idea of build reproducibility, i.e. the same revision in your version control should always build in the same way. For that, it is important that all version numbers are explicitly given in the pom, so that, in a year's time, the build of the same revision will behave in the same way.

Comment: I understand. But the plugins are not thirdparty libs. The plugins are from our own project and every version can be used in the pom.xml. For us is important that the newest version will be always used.

Comment: This is just not how Maven works. Automatically using the latest plugin version means that a future build is not completely equivalent to the build now.

Answer (score 1):

The `RELEASE` and `LATEST` features were removed with good reason: Maven aims for reproducible builds, whose purpose is defeated if the version that comes with each execution is not the same. In order to keep your project up-to-date, you could run [`mvn versions:use-latest-releases`](https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/use-latest-releases-mojo.html), check that everything works, and commit the updated POM.